# Finding a periodic bijection on the set of bitstrings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the set of bitstrings of length $n$. For $x\in S$, let $W(x)$ be the Hamming weight of $x$ i.e. number of ones in $x$.

> I am trying to find a bijection $f:S\to S$ which maps bitstrings in the following periodic manner. Bitstrings of low weight are mapped to bitstrings of medium weight. Then bitstrings of medium weight are mapped to bitstrings of high weight and finally the high weight ones are mapped back to low weight ones.

My attempt: Consider $x\in S$. If we take the $XOR$ of the $n-$bits of $x$, append the result to $x$ and pop the first bit of $x$ to get a bitstring say $y$. Then let $f(x)=y$ defines a bijection. But this bijection doesn't satisfy the above requirements because $W(f(x))=W(x)+1$ if $W(x)$ is odd and the first bit of $x$ is $0$ and $W(f(x))=W(x)-1$ if $W(x)$ is even and the first bit of $x$ is $1$.

So with this $f$, we move up/down a weight class depending on whether the current weight is odd/even and it's clearly not periodic. So instead of moving up/down, I would like a bijection that only goes up weight classes initially, then we reach medium weight at which point we need to go down weight classes as described above.

I've gotten very helpful answers on other types of bijections on $S$ here before. This is a part of a larger problem I'm working on: Random walk on the set of bitstrings and this $f$ helps me shuffle the bitstrings so that the random walk converges to its stationary distribution faster.

**EDIT:** Just a note on the comment below by Ross. If we map weight $1$ strings to weight $2$ strings and so on and keep the remaining strings mapped to themselves, then a whole lot of strings do not change weight because they are mapped to themselves. I am trying to avoid that. The strings don't have to change weight only by $1$. Also, a lot of strings need to change weight as opposed to the previous example.

Comment: You can't do this with a bijection.  If you map low weight strings to something of higher weight, you can't map the high weight strings to low weight strings.  Every bijection has to partition the set into singletons and pairs.  The singletons are mapped to themselves and the elements of the pairs are mapped to each other.  You can have an injection that does roughly what you want, but a weight $1$ string could be mapped to a weight $2$ string, that is mapped to a weight $3$ string, etc.  Do you insist that the weight of a string always change under the mapping?

Comment: @RossMillikan Good point, I don't insist that the weight always change but change as much as possible to get a bijection. Like in the example above for one string of $w=2$, which is mapped to itself, the weight did not change.

Comment: @RossMillikan May be my explanation was not clear. Consider $n=4$,let $w$ be the weight of a string, we have $1$ string of $w=0,4$; $4$ strings of $w=1,3$ and $6$ strings of $w=2$. So if we can map $1$ string of $w=0$ and $4$ strings of $w=1$, i.e. a total of $5$ strings, to $w=2$, map those $5$ strings of $w=2$ to strings of $w=3,4$ and finally map the $5$ strings of $w=3,4$ back to strings of $w=0,1$, then this is a bijection. There is one remaining string of $w=2$ which can be mapped to itself.

Comment: I had been thinking of a bijection within a set as having to be self inverse, but that is not true.  You can certainly list the elements of the set in some order and have your mapping just step forward some number of steps in the cycle.  If you use an order by weight and then lexicographic the four bit order is $0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,9,10,12,7,11,13,14,15$  You could take each bit string to the one that is one or a few spaces later, for example.

Comment: @RossMillikan True, but I'm looking for a formula for such an $f$ because otherwise that is a lot of bookkeeping for large $n$ and makes proofs in the random walk problem that  I'm solving hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with an order that has the numbers sorted by number of bits, then lexicographically.  For four bits, that would give the order $0,1,2,4,8,3,5,6,9,10,12,7,11,13,14,15$.  Then you can write a function that steps you once along the order.  If the lowest bit is $1$ it looks at the string of $1$ bits from the bottom and shifts the top one into the place above.  If the lowest bit is $0$ it looks at the lowest $1$.  If it has a $0$ above it it shifts that $1$ by one place.  If it has a $1$ above it, it shifts the top of the string of $1$s up one place and all the lower $1$s into the lowest places.  If it carries out the top it just fills one more bit from the bottom than the previous word had.  You need special rules for $0 \to 1$ and all $1$s $\to 0$.  Now choose a number of steps to go each time.  For the four bit one, three steps is reasonable, giving an order of $0,4,5,10,11,15,2,3,9,12,13,1,8,6,12,13$  Maybe you would prefer five steps, giving an order of $0,3,12,15,8,10,14,4,9,13,2,6,11,1,5,7$.  Now only $3$ has the same weight as its successor.

Comment: I see, I didn't understand where you've used this function that's described? In the three step and five step orderings described in the end, you are stepping through the original order with increments of three/five, so didn't get where this function is used? Are you saying that the function described lets us take a step of size one? Thanks.

Comment: The function would be used to make the list that I step through-the one that starts $0,1,2,4,8$.  You could either make and store the list for your desired number of bits, or just start with $0$ and call it three times to get $4$.  If you have at least $6$ bits three more calls will get $32$ and so on.  The advantage of writing it as a function instead of storing the list is that it is random access.  You can feed it any number you want and get the next one in the list.  If you have room to store the list twice you can get random access from position to number and from number to position.

Comment: I see, thanks..

Comment: So the bijection for the three step one for $ n=4$ would be: $f(0)=4,f(4)=5,f(5)=10\cdots$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks, "If it carries out the top it just fills one more bit from the bottom than the previous word had". Does this mean $f(11100)=00111$? Just confirming.

Comment: No, there has to be one more bit filled, so $f(11100)=01111$.  $11100$ is the last of the three weight words in the order.